# Reemplazar texto dentro de un cuadro de texto en un encabezado en word vb.net

Tags: vb.net

En un archivo de word que uso como plantilla para generar oficios, tengo la necesidad de reemplazar texto de un **cuadro de texto** que esta dentro del encabezado del documento, si esta en el cuerpo del documento ya logre reemplazarlo pero no cuando esta dentro del encabezado, adjunto mi código esperando me puedan orientar, saludos

la parte del código es

```
    With objWord.ActiveWindow

        .ActivePane.View.SeekView = WdSeekView.wdSeekCurrentPageHeader 

        For Each SHP In .ActivePane.Document.Shapes
            If SHP.Type = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoShapeType.msoTextBox Then
                SHP.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Replace(SHP.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, "[reemp_asunto]", "Next Text")
                SHP.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Replace(SHP.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, "[reemp_oficio]", "fff Text")
            End If
        Next 
        end with
```

lo que intento es que al abrir el documento se active la parte del
**header** para que encuentre el **cuadro de texto** y reemplace el texto dentro de el pero no lo hace, si ese mismo **cuadro de texto** lo saco del encabezado y lo pongo sobre el cuerpo del documento si me lo reemplaza, ¿cual seria el código correcto para lograrlo dentro del encabezado del documento?.

Uso Visual Studio 2012 en VB.net y me refiero a esto [image: Cuadro de texto dentro del encabezado del documento]

Comment: ¿Cuál es el nombre del campo en el encabezado?

Comment: Perdón no entiendo a que te refieres por nombre del campo en el encabezado

Comment: Abert, asumí que en el encabezado/header había un campo *(como el que muestras [reemp_oficio])*. Una solución a tu problema es: editar la plantilla de Word para agregar un nuevo campo en el encabezado. Así en tu código haces referencia al campo del encabezado.